# Make a field to mixed case

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

`Patient.name`'s actual data is in Caps. I have to make it mixed case date for nicer viewing. Can I do this here on the XAML? How can I code this?

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Patient.Name" />
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Patient.Room" />
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Patient.BirthDate" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a property that wraps Patient.Room etc. with code that converts to title case and bind to that property instead.

Your binding:

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Patient.RoomTitleCase" />
```

In your class:

```
public string RoomTitleCase
{
    get
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo =     
                 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        System.Globalization.TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

        string titleCase = textInfo.ToTitleCase(Room.ToLower());
        return titleCase;
    }
}
```

http://techiecocktail.blogspot.com/2008/09/convert-given-string-to-mixed-case-or.html

Comment: Note that this will presumably turn MCDONALD into Mcdonald, not McDonald.  The first two lines can be shortened to `var textInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;` (with proper `using`)